# Datatype conversion in IBM DB2: BIGINT to VARCHAR

Tags: sql, db2, udb

I'm writing a query to do some stuff. But its not working the way I want it to:

```
select CORR_ID from TABLE1
where CORR_ID not in (select id from TABLE2)
```

The problem is, TABLE2.id is a long, while TABLE1.CORR_ID is a string.

So how can I make it work?

PS: I'm using IBM UDB.

Comment: Title phrasing is very important if you want to attract people to your question. "My query is broken" is a kind of title most people will ignore. However, if your title indicates you have a specific problem people will be more likely to take a closer look.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay, I found a method:

```
select CORR_ID from TABLE1 where CORR_ID not in 
(select CAST( CAST(id AS CHAR(50)) AS VARCHAR(50) ) from TABLE2)
```

This is pretty intriguing: You can't cast a BIGINT to VARCHAR, but:

- you can cast a BIGINT to CHAR
- and you can cast a CHAR TO VARCHAR

this is ridiculous!

Answer (score 2):

DB2 allows a VARCHAR and CHAR column to be compared without additional casting, so all you really need to do is cast the number.

SELECT corr_id FROM table1 WHERE corr_id NOT IN (SELECT CHAR( id ) FROM table2 )

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cast the selected id column to match the data type of corr_id

select CORR_ID from TABLE1
where CORR_ID not in (select cast(id as varchar) from TABLE2)

Comment: much better than my answer.  I'd vote it up if I had 2 more rep points